# Why is this differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a complex valued Lebesgue integrable function over R, show that the function $g(t)= \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\exp(-itx) \, dx$ is differentiable. I cannot seem to find a dominating $L^1$ function in order to apply differentiation under the integral sign. Any alternative ideas? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't $|f(x)|$ do the trick? The norm of $e^{-itx}$ is 1, after all...

Comment: No, I require a dominating function for the derivative of the integrand, or for the difference f(x){exp(-itx)-exp(-isx)}/(t-s), I don't know how else to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fix an $x$.  Consider $\frac{g(t+h) - g(t)}{h} =  \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-itx}(\frac{e^{-ihx} - 1}{h}) dx$.

Notice that $\frac{e^{-ihx} -1}{h} = \frac{-i}{h} \int_0^{hx} e^{-is} ds$, from which we obtain the estimate $|\frac{e^{-ihx} - 1}{h}| \le 1$.  So the integrand is bounded by $|f|$, and the differentiation under the integral sign follows by appealing to the dct.

Comment: That cannot possibly be correct since the limit (exp(-ihx)-1)/h as h->0 is homogeneous with respect to x, so it cannot possibly be uniformly bounded for all x in R.

Comment: You're correct.  The estimate would actually be $|\frac{e^{-ihx} - 1}{h}| \le |x|$.  I apologize for the hasty and incorrect response.

Answer (score 1):

There is something amiss with the question. For example, the functions $f_\alpha(x)=1/(x+i)^\alpha\,$ have Fourier transforms $\hat{f}_\alpha$ equal to $c_\alpha\cdot x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}$ for $x>0$, and $0$ for $x<0$, for constants $c_\alpha$, for $\Re(\alpha)>1$ at least. (This is most easily computed by computing the Fourier transform of the function that is $0$ for $x<0$ and $x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}$ for $x>0$, by Gamma-function machinations.) For $\alpha=1+\epsilon\,$ the function is in $L^1\cap L^2$, but its Fourier transform is not differentiable at $0$. (That is, the conclusion of differentiability is not correct as posed...)